# JQuery click code not getting executed

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

When I click on the play button, the alert- 'User clicked on 'foo' must've been displayed, but thats not happenening. ie the jquery click handler is not being invoked!

```
<html>
        <head>
          <script type = "text/javascript" src ="new.js"></script>
          <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
          <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <button type="button" id = "play" name = "play" value = "play">PLAY</button>
            <button onclick = "pauseAd()" type ="button" name = "pause" value = "pause">PAUSE</button>
            </br>
            <audio controls id = "song">
                <source src = "Lyrics to Swallowed in the Sea - Coldplay.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" >
            </audio>

            <script>
                var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

                $(function() {
                    $('#play').bind('click',function(){
                        alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
                        socket.emit('msg', {sent : 1});
                        return false;
                    });
                });


                socket.on('msg-received', function(data) {
                    if(data.value = 1) {
                        $('#play').click();
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, if you strip it down to what you are asking. Most likely it's something in else in your code causing the error.

```
<!-- Bare-Bones HTML CODE -->
<button type="button" id="play" name="play" value="play">PLAY</button>

// JavaScript
$(function() {
  $('#play').bind('click', function() {
    alert("User clicked on 'foo.'");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Do you see any errors in the web inspector or debugger on your browser?

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/cjboco/pen/oYrPPX) of the working code (stripped down).

Comment: 404 error on GET jquery-3.1.1.min.js
But I have this js file in the same directory as my above html file.

Comment: If you are getting a 404 error on jQuery, then that means is not loading.